# Default XSD attribute use indicator values?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmlschema

What are default values of indicators in XSD Schema when they aren't define directly?

How many times (min and max) and what order in should (or can) I define attributes of `foo` in XML?

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:attribute name="name1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name2" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

P.S. This example is for a real and working project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD the [`xsd:attribute/@use`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-attribute) attribute determines whether an XML attribute *may*, *must*, or *must not* appear:

- `optional`: The attribute *may* appear but need not.  This is the default value.
- `required`: The attribute *must* appear.
- `prohibited`: The attribute *must not* appear.

In XML there can only be at most a single attribute with a given name per element, and the order of attributes is insignificant.

### See also

- [Setting the order of attributes for XML in XSD (XML Schema)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19263907/290085)
- [Where does xsd:attribute declaration go? (A problem was found starting at: attribute.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40452169/290085)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case attribute may appear once (it is analogue of `minOccurs=0, maxOccurs=1` in elements) . [See table 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints)